# Create COM or SOM?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

When you create a new solution for SharePoint in VS 2012, are you creating a new client object model or server object model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the template you choose,

- If you choose SharePoint 2013 - Empty project as you project
  template, it will be a Server Object Model project
- If you choose App for SharePoint 2013, then it will be an app, and if you choose SharePoint hosted, you can only use Client Object Model (by javascript)

With that said, a SharePoint 2013 - Empty project, can contain both SOM and COM code.

Comment: How aboout webpart?

Comment: A webpart is also part on the solutions, it is not an app. But you can create a kind of webpart in an app, an AppPart.